# How to use google cloud function as singleton

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I would like to use create a google cloud function and use it as singleton. I know this isn't the behavior inteded to these functions but i couldn't find another item in google cloud infrastructure better suited todo what i need.

In simple words what i need is a global remote counter able to handle hundreds of accesses per second.

i tried firebase database with transaction but it didnt handle well the high concurrency.

then i created a fcm and adjusted a set of mechanisms to make it a singleton... for after the first instance successfully starts any new instanced created automatically by google infrastructure is killed (i cant stop google from creating them but i can kill them).

but there is one problem...

for some reason i dont know, google sometimes kills the SINGLETON instance.
when that happens no new instance can be created to my function (due the code design)... i was reading firebase documentation and then i found:

> A new function instance is started in two cases:
>
> When you deploy your function.
>
> When a new function instance is automatically created to scale up to
>   the load, or occasionally to replace an existing instance.
>   https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#function_scope_vs_global_scope

what does it mean: `or occasionally to replace an existing instance.` so google kill instances just for fun?

has anyone achieved successfully the behavior of singleton using fcm?
does anyone have a better idea of how creating a counter using google infrastructure?

thanks

Comment: Do you need sync answer? Or you just need to increase your counter, and async mode can work for you?

Comment: i just need to increase the counter and answer the request. sync or async doesn't matter but must be able to handle hundreds of requests per sec

Answer (score 1):

> so google kill instances just for fun?

No, this is just the way Cloud Functions works (and serverless products in general).  Cloud Functions will scale up server instances as needed to accommodate current load (up to 1000 server instances per background function), and will scale back down to 0 instances when there is no load.  It will also occasionally replace a server instance after some time in order to ensure that memory leaks don't become a problem, or to publish OS updates to an instance (for example, security patches).

There are no free, persistent server instances provided by Cloud Functions.  If you want a persistent server instance that doesn't go away until you say so, you will have to use another product, such as Compute Engine or App Engine, or change your strategy entirely.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is the following. I recommend you to have a more complex architecture.

- Function1: this function get all the message from outside. This function can scale and process message in parallel. The gotten messages are published into PubSub. Why? My target is to miss any messages. The PubSub is like a buffer to store the message
- PubSub subscription with a
- Function2: triggered by PubSub messages `--trigger-topic` and with a [max-instance = 1](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances). This function increment the counter. The function can handle only 1 request at a time and the max instance is 1 and thus you will process only 1 message at a time.
- Firestore: increment your counter in firestore.

Firestore can be a bottleneck and/or I fear that you will reach the free tier of the write if you have hundreds of message per seconds. If so, you can add additional layer.

- Use Memory store for incrementing the counter in a very fast in memory redis database.
- Use function2: for making the update on Memory store
- Write a fonction 3, called by Cloud Scheduler, at the frequency that you want for reading into Memory store and update periodically the counter into Firestore.

There is also others pattern, more complex more expensive with BigQuery, BigTable, Dataflow,.... I don't really what you want to achieve and your budget for this!

Hope it's a good start for you!

Comment: what exactly is memory store?

Comment: [Memorystore is a managed Redis database](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis). Redis is an in memory and very efficient key-value database, design for high throughput.